# Recording audio not to file on Android

Tags: java, android

I want android.media.MediaRecorder. to record audio not into file, but into same variable, for example char[ ] or byte[ ] or some other datta buffer structure. I want to send it to the remote server via Wi-Fi, can android.media.MediaRecorder provide this functionality?

Comment: It is possible. The MediaRecorder writes to a FileDescriptor not necessarily to a File. Note that this is not "streaming"! You'll have to write to a file on server-side again. This may help: http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system

Comment: actually you can create a file descriptor that simply writes to an internal buffer instead of a file, also don't forget that sockets have a file descriptor as well, which you write to in order to write to the socket. there is also no need to write a file server side as long as something is listening on the correct socket address to receive those packets and process them accordingly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you can do here is utilize the ParcelFileDescriptor class.

```
//make a pipe containing a read and a write parcelfd
ParcelFileDescriptor[] fdPair = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();

//get a handle to your read and write fd objects.
ParcelFileDescriptor readFD = fdPair[0];
ParcelFileDescriptor writeFD = fdPair[1];

//next set your mediaRecorder instance to output to the write side of this pipe.
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(writeFD.getFileDescriptor());

//next create an input stream to read from the read side of the pipe.
FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream(readFD.getFileDescriptor());

//now to fill up a buffer with data, we just do a simple read
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];//or w/e buffer size you want

//fill up your buffer with data from the stream
reader.read(buffer);// may want to do this in a separate thread
```

and now you have a buffer full of audio data

alternatively, you may want to write data directly to a socket from the recorder. this can also be achieved with the ParcelFileDescriptor class.

```
//create a socket connection to another device
Socket socket = new Socket("123.123.123.123",65535);//or w/e socket address you are using

//wrap the socket with a parcel so you can get at its underlying File descriptor
ParcelFileDescriptor socketWrapper = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);

//set your mediaRecorder instance to write to this file descriptor
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(socketWrapper.getFileDescriptor());
```

now any time your media recorder has data to write it will automatically write it over the socket

Comment: Note that (as far as I know) you can't use non seekable output (like pipes) with mediarecorder except if you use the output format AMR_NB